# Problem in getting records from last 13 months in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I am working on to get records from last 13 months using following MySQL query:

```
SELECT YEAR(`customer_date`),
       MONTHNAME(`customer_date`),
       COUNT(`customer_date`) AS Enquiries
FROM   `crm_customers`
WHERE  DATE(`customer_date`) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 month AND
                                     CURRENT_DATE
GROUP  BY YEAR(`customer_date`),
          MONTH(`customer_date`)
ORDER  BY YEAR(`customer_date`) DESC,
          MONTH(`customer_date`) DESC
```

My prototype MySQL table **crm_customers** looks as:

```
customer_id    customer_date
1              2019-02-01 00:00:00
2              2019-02-02 00:00:00
...            ...
...            ...
...            ...
```

Output:

[image]

Though above query does work fine and gives me almost correct result set except one issue related to very last month of the last year from a gap of 13 months from today.

Today is 7th of March 2020. The date condition in my above query

```
WHERE  DATE(`customer_date`) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 month AND CURRENT_DATE
```

starts fetching the result from 7th of Feb 2019.

In the month of Feb, 2019 I have 104 entries. But my above SQL fetches only 80 entries because 24 entries are before 07-Feb-2019 (between 1 Feb and 6 Feb 2019). I want to include those entries as well. How can I modify my date condition to achieve the required result.

**EDIT**

Why this question is marked negative? I don't understand. Question is very much clear and not duplicated. Is it down voted by GMB?

Comment: What do you expected? Current month(2020-02) to 13 months (2019-02) between data? Or Current date(2020-02-07) to 13 months ago date(2019-02-07)?

Comment: @Tushar the data between 2019-02-01 to 2020-03-07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE  DATE(`customer_date`) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 13 month AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibility to achieve this

```
SELECT CURDATE()
, CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
,LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Results in

```
CURDATE() , CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE), LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
2020-03-07, 2020-03-01                                  , 2020-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to reduce precision in your `DATE` value. Use [`EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) for this;

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 MONTH)
```

Comment: This is not giving me correct output. It fetches the result set from Jan 2017. I want to get data only from last 13 months ago till today.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
where 
    customer_date >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval 13 month
    and customer_date < current_date + interval 1 day
```

Rationale:

- this compares the stored date without prior transformation (while your query, and all answers so far, use `date()`), which makes it possible to benefit an existing index - on a large dataset, this can make a big performance difference
- date arithmetics is as simple as possible; MySQL happily treats strings in proper formats as dates, which can shorten the syntax

Comment: Though your query does work fine but I don't need an extra day in `current_date + interval 1 day`. Rather I want to fetch records till today back to 13 months.

Comment: Also don't use lowercase for MySQL reserved keywords. Use UPPERCASE e.g. CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL, etc. which helps in easy reading and understanding the query.

Comment: @Sachin: then you can just change `customer_date < current_date + interval 1 day` to `customer_date < current_date`. Upper/lower case is a matter of taste, you can change it as you want. Why I answered is because I believe that this solution is more efficient than others, due to SARGable filters on dates (ie may take advantage of an index).

Comment: I don't think its just a matter of taste or personal preferences. Believe me if you use proper variable/keyword/function naming conventions as suggested by coding experts then they definitely improve in coding readability and understanding even in first glance. When you wrote `current_date` and I saw it at first glance, I just realized that it might be yours custom alias. But when I wrote `CURRENT_DATE`, people who have read my question clearly understood that it must be a MySQL reserved keyword/function for date section. I hope you will understand my logic.